# Finding travelers to Germany from Hungary by car

Tags: germany, hungary

I am planing to go to Germany between the end of this month and the beginning of next month.

Checking the flights, are pretty expensive. So I thought maybe there's a place I can find travellers by car and maybe agree on a certain price to ride with them.

Comment: “Ride sharing” is called “Mitfahrgelegenheit” in German, looking for that word on Google yields several useful results. Alternatively, you might want to consider a bus.

Comment: +1 for Relaxed answer. Many people especially from Poland, Czech Repulic and Hungary use bus connections because they are comparatively cheap.

Answer (score 3):

For travels from Hungary, try these carshare services (most of them don't have English websites, but just fill fields "honnan" = from and "hová" = to):

http://utitars.oszkar.com/

http://www.blablacar.hu/